# Divide the second value of each key with the first value of each key inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I would like for this dictionary to obtain the ratio `ln(value2/value1)` (i.e., `ln(94.77730877)/ln(47.82938075)`) for every key.

`{'HKUST1_MOF': [94.77730877, 47.82938075], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [119.2920858, 55.70192895]}`

I tried something like the code below to see if it works, which it is, but I cannot modify it so that I can actually calculate the desired value (ratio `ln(value2/value1)` for every key).

These are the desired results.
`{'HKUST1_MOF': [-0.683890743], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [-0.76156021]}`

This is the code I used.
**for key in d1:**

```py
d1[key] = [val/mean(d1[key]) for val in d1[key]]
```

Comment: You question is inconsistent ... these are **not** the same thing: “ln(value2/value1) (i.e., ln(94.77730877)/ln(47.82938075))”

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension if each value in the dictionary values is a list object as:

```
x = {'HKUST1_MOF': [94.77730877, 47.82938075], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [119.2920858, 55.70192895]}
x = {k : v[0]/v[1] for k, v in x.items()}
print(x)
```

Combining this with `log`, the output you need can be obtained with:

```
from math import log
x = {'HKUST1_MOF': [94.77730877, 47.82938075], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [119.2920858, 55.70192895]}
x = {k : [(log(v[1]/v[0]))] for k, v in x.items()}
print(x)
```

Output:

```
{'HKUST1_MOF': [-0.6838899109306623], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [-0.7615602108684435]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment! Solved!!!

Comment: Awesome @AmvrosiosGeorgiadis, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of every `key` in the `dict` is a `list` (ex: [94.77730877, 47.82938075]) you need to `index` it to get the values and then you can take the ratio

```py
from math import log

d1 = {'HKUST1_MOF': [94.77730877, 47.82938075], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [119.2920858, 55.70192895]}

for key in d1:
    d1[key] = log(d1[key][1]/d1[key][0]) # i.e. log(second_element / first_element)
```

```
{'HKUST1_MOF': -0.6838899109306623, 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': -0.7615602108684435}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = {'HKUST1_MOF': [94.77730877, 47.82938075], 'HKUST1_MOF_MCM41': [119.2920858, 55.70192895]}
foo = {bar : i[0]/i[1] for bar, i in foo.items()}
```